# Java implementation of "==" for Integer objects with value from -128 to 127

Tags: java, performance, integer, comparison, equals

I found a lot of questions about **comparing objects** in Java. **Primitive** types we can compare using `==` for example `int`

```
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    int i3 = 1000;
    int i4 = 1000;
    int i5 = 1;
    int i6 = 2;

    System.out.println(i1 == i2);
    System.out.println(i3 == i4);
    System.out.println(i5 == i6);
```

output is

```
true
true
false
```

When we want to compare `Integer` objects we can do it in two ways

```
equals()
```

and here we are comparing **values**

```
    Integer i1 = 0;
    Integer i2 = 0;
    Integer i3 = 1000;
    Integer i4 = 1000;
    Integer i5 = 1;
    Integer i6 = 2;

    System.out.println(i1.equals(i2));
    System.out.println(i3.equals(i4));
    System.out.println(i5.equals(i6));
```

output is

```
true
true
false
```

or we can use `==` which compares **references**.

Let's take two String variables with the same value

```
    String s1 = "Yes, this is dog";
    String s2 = "Yes, this is dog";

    System.out.println(s1 == s2);
    System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
```

It is well-known that results of both comparisons will be true

```
true
true
```

So now, I want to do this same with Integer objects.  I run this piece of code

```
    Integer i1 = 0;
    Integer i2 = 0;
    Integer i3 = 1000;
    Integer i4 = 1000;
    Integer i5 = 1;
    Integer i6 = 2;

    System.out.println(i1 == i2);
    System.out.println(i3 == i4);
    System.out.println(i5 == i6);
```

and the output is

```
true
false
false
```

We can meet this kind of behavior for Integer objects with these values: `[-128,127]`

```
    for (int i = -129;i <129;i++) {
        Integer i1 = i;
        Integer i2 = i;
        System.out.println(i1 == i2);
    }
```

output:

```
false
true
...
false
```

I would like to know, what is the reason of this behavior? Does it have a big influence to **performance**?

In which **package** and in which **class** can I find a piece of code which takes care of this situation?

In which Java version it has been introduced and is it be maintained in **Java 8**?

If I want to change this behaviour, am I able to do that or I should use operator `new` each time?

```
Integer i = new Integer(1024);
```

Thank you in advance