# This is my Code. In this case It will show output as Not equal. But if I pass input less than 128 then it will give output as Equal

Tags: java, integer

```
class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Integer i=128;
        Integer j=128;
        if(i==j){
            System.out.println("Equal");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Not Equal");
        }

    }

}
```

This is my Code. In this case It will show output as Not equal. But if I pass input less than 128 then it will give output as Equal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529843/java-implementation-of-for-integer-objects-with-value-from-128-to-127?lq=1

Comment: Read more about [integer cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130311/weird-integer-boxing-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're comparing `Integer` *instances* (which are objects) with `==`. When you compare objects with `==`, you're checking that they're the **same object**, not that they're equivalent.

So why does it work with values less than 128? Because the JVM caches and reuses `Integer` instances for those values. You're using *autoboxing* by assigning primitives to `Integer` variables, and boxing uses [`Integer.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-). From the JavaDoc:

> This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

But for other values, it (probably) creates new instances as you go.

For what you're doing, use `int` primitives instead of `Integer` instances. If you ever need to use `Integer` instances, compare them with `equals` instead of `==`.

```
if (i.equals(j))
```